# mocha test fail because this is undefined in mongoose pre validate hooks model (even without arrow function)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mocha.js

I'm testing a post request that basically registers users to db.
my mocha test fails because this is undefined when the *pre* validate hooks is triggered. I'm already using a normal function instead of an arrow function. It works perfectly in `postman/insomnia`. the problem occurs if I'm testing it through mocha.

```
userSchema.pre('validate', function(next) {

    if (this.password.split(' ').length > 1) {
        next(new Error('password can not contain a white space'));
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Comment: can you share your test file?

Answer (score 0):

For access to this it should be separate function

```
function preValidateFunction(next) {
    if (this.password.split(' ').length > 1) {
        next(new Error('password can not contain a white space'));
    } else {
        next();
    }
}

userSchema.pre('validate', preValidateFunction);
```